# Generated Picture Filesize Upload for RSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I upload a picture via paperclip (in rails). This picture will appear in the rss feed. For the RSS feed, I need to fill the field length which tells the client the file length I guess.

It would be easy for the attached file itself, because the there is a column file_size, but what if the picture is post-process and I want to include this picture, how do I get the file size?

Code:

pic.rb

```
class Pic < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image, 
                    :styles => { 
                      :mail => "780x540>", 
                      :medium => "260x180>", 
                      :thumb => "130x90>",
                    }, 
                    :storage => :s3
end
```

rss.rb

```
xml.instruct! :xml, version: "1.0" 
xml.rss version: "2.0" do
  xml.channel do

    @ps.each do |p|
        xml.item do
        xml.title       p.title
        xml.description p.description.truncate(250)
        xml.pubDate     p.starts_at.to_s(:rfc822)
        xml.link        p.uri_name
        xml.guid        p.uri_name
        xml.enclosure   url: p.pic(:medium), type: "image/jpeg", length: ??
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Should be easy, but..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Because it's stored on s3, I can get the information via http..

in pic.rb

```
  def content_length(size)
    parts = URI.parse image.url(size)
    Net::HTTP.start(parts.host, parts.port) do |http|
      response = http.request_head parts.path
      file_size = response['content-length']
    end
  end
```